# Can not open aux file with AASTeX template

Tags: auxiliary-files, aastex

Yesterday, I tried to use a template AASTeX from AAS website. https://journals.aas.org/aastex-package-for-manuscript-preparation/

After downloading the source file from this website, I tried to compile the source file. Although TexStudio can show the content on the right screen, my TexStudio enunciates that ``I couldn't open file name `sample631.aux'''. Despite the fact that I changed some text in the content, the result still did not change after compiling. I hope I can receive the support from all of you.

You can find my problem in the following image.
[image]
[image]